# How to go to the next item in a slice

Tags: for-loop, go, slice, goland

I have written the following code to get the next item in an array.

```
count:=len(value.Values)
for index, currentRow := range value.Values {
    var nextRow Value
    if index< count{
    nextRow = value.Values[index+1]
    fmt.Print(nextRow)
    }
}
```

I am getting a panic when running the above code.

Goroutine panic: runtime error: index out of range

Any idea of how can I get the next item from a slice.

Comment: First a note on terminology: Are you using slices or arrays? They _are not the same thing_

Comment: Second, you're successfully getting the "next item", but when you're on the last one, there is no next item, thus the panic. The solution depends on your goal.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Flimzy that's right I am getting the next item, but getting a panic when there is no next item. My goal is to get the next item from the slice without getting a panic if there is no next item.

Comment: Then choose one of the solutions in the answer below: Either skip the check when you're already on the last one, or only iterate through `n-1` elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The next item is indeed `value.Values[index+1]`, but if `index` is the index of the last element, there is no next item, in that case `index+1` is an invalid index to `value.Values` and attempting to use it results in a runtime panic.

So do check the index:

```
for index, currentRow := range value.Values {
    var nextRow Value
    if index < timeSeriesDataCount && index < len(value.Values)-1 {
        nextRow = value.Values[index+1]
        fmt.Print(nextRow)
    }
}
```

Another option is to range over a slice that is one-less (exclude the last element), so no need to check the `index`, there is surely another element:

```
for index, currentRow := range value.Values[:len(value.Values)-1] {
    var nextRow Value
    if index < timeSeriesDataCount {
        nextRow = value.Values[index+1]
        fmt.Print(nextRow)
    }
}
```

What you do have to think about in this case is if the `value.Values` is empty, because if it is, the above slicing operation will again panic, so do check that:

```
if len(value.Values) > 0 {
    for index, currentRow := range value.Values[:len(value.Values)-1] {
        var nextRow Value
        if index < timeSeriesDataCount {
            nextRow = value.Values[index+1]
            fmt.Print(nextRow)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we could check if `len(value.Values) > 1` because even though there won't be panic if `len = 1`, there will be `0` iterations.

Also note that ranging over a slice that excludes the last element does not visit the last element (obviously), so if you'd do anything else with the elements, this might not be viable, but in your example they are equivalent.